# parralel stream syntax prior to java 8 release

Tags: parallel-processing, java-8, release, java-stream

Prior to the Java 8 official release, when it was still in development, am I correct in thinking the syntax of getting streams and parallel streams was slightly different. Now we have the option of either saying:

`stream().parallel()` or `parallelStream()`

I remember reading tutorials before its release when there was a subtle difference here - can anyone remind of of what it was as it has been bugging me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current implementation has no difference: `.stream()` creates a pipeline with `parallel` field set to `false`, then `.parallel()` just sets this field to true and returns the same object. When using `.parallelStream()`, it creates the pipeline with `parallel` field set to `true` in constructor. So both versions are the same. Any consequent calls to `.parallel()` or `.sequential()` just do the same: change the stream mode flag to `true` or `false` and return the same object.

The early implementation of Stream API was different. [Here's](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/lambda/lambda/jdk/file/7409900b4cf8/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/AbstractPipeline.java#l327) the source code of `AbstractPipeline` (parent for all `Stream`, `IntStream`, `LongStream` and `DoubleStream` implementations) in lambda-dev just before the logic was changed. Setting the mode to `parallel()` right after the stream is created from the spliterator was relatively cheap: it just extracts spliterator from the original stream (`depth == 0` branch in `spliteratorSupplier()`), then creates a new stream on the top of this spliterator discarding the original stream (those times there were no `close()/onClose()`, so it was unnecessary to delegate close handlers).

Nevertheless if your stream source included intermediate steps (for example, consider [`Collections.nCopies`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/lambda/lambda/jdk/file/7409900b4cf8/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java#l4155) implementation which includes `map` step), the things were worse: using `.stream().parallel()` would [create a new spliterator](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/lambda/lambda/jdk/file/7409900b4cf8/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/ReferencePipeline.java#l105) with poor-man splitting strategy (which includes buffering). So for such collection using `.parallelStream()` was actually better as it used internally `.parallel()` *before* the intermediate operation. Currently even for `nCopies()` you can use both `.stream().parallel()` and `.parallelStream()` interchangeably.

Going even more backwards, you [may notice](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/lambda/lambda/jdk/file/cbef342202eb/src/share/classes/java/util/Collection.java#l491) that `.parallelStream()` was called simply `.parallel()` initially. It was renamed in [this changeset](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/lambda/lambda/jdk/rev/e41e14b4470a).

Comment: But wasn't there a slight difference in syntax as well - I remember reading something that suggested this had or was being changed for the final release, so for example you could call collection.stream() or collection.parallel() and they changed it to collection.parallelStream() and stream().parallel(). That is just an example, but it was something like this I think...

Comment: Well, going even more backwards, you [may notice](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/lambda/lambda/jdk/file/cbef342202eb/src/share/classes/java/util/Collection.java#l491) that `.parallelStream()` was called `.parallel()` initially, if you are asking about this. It was  renamed in [this changeset](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/lambda/lambda/jdk/rev/e41e14b4470a).

Comment: Yes that was it!! Was driving me mad as I knew there was a change. So when it used to be called .parallel() and not .parallelStream() was there still stream().parallel(), i.e. the method that changed a sequential stream to be parallel? If so I guess that's why they changed it, as there was a conflict in that sense and it's more obvious now.

Comment: @user3780370, yes [`Stream.parallel()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/lambda/lambda/jdk/file/5d25f6772fec/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/ReferencePipeline.java#l172) was already there. New name is indeed less confusing.